# How to include intermittent, to the job consulting on resume?

Tags: resume, job-search, job-description

My resume is currently organized in a standard format with **Job title**, **city/location**, **description**, **start** and **end** dates for each job or internship that I have held in the past.

I do have one company (actually my father's engineering firm) which I provide consulting/assistance to in an intermittent manner. Meaning they call me for small well-defined jobs which I then execute in short time periods of one to two weeks. This has been going on for a little while (Maybe the last two years?) but has provided me with valuable experience which I need to be able to list for some of my job applications.

How do I successfully include this "position" without deviating from my established, tried and true format. Specifically I would like to know what relevant **Job title**, **city/location**, **description**, **start** and **end** date type data fields that would accurately represent it on a standard form resume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just describe it as part time/intermittent consulting work, and use the first time you did work for them and either the last time you finished something or present (if you're still available for new tasks as they come up) for the end date.  Something like this:

> **Part Time Young Kitten Cuddling Consultant, Momma Kitty's House**
>
> Provided tummy rubs and ... on an as needed basis averaging 10 or 20 hours over 3 month intervals, 1 to 3 times per year.
>
> **January 14, 2011 to present**

I ordered the fields as you described them; but would probably put the date range at the start of the block not the end.

Sort it with your other work by end date.  Unless there were long intervals where you weren't available to consult there's no need or benefit in listing each item separately.